# Is this the most efficient way to split one array into 2 more?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm having a bit of a mental block, but is there a more efficient way of creating 2 new arrays, from values in another array?

Here is my current example and while it works, I feel there may be a more efficient method;

Original Array;

```
const daily = [
    {event_date: "2019-10-18", listener: 3},
    {event_date: "2019-10-19", listener: 3},
    {event_date: "2019-10-20", listener: 1}
];
```

What I need to do, is create 2 new arrays, one with the `event_date` values and the other with the `listener` values.

I am using `map` to achieve this like so;

```
const dailyLabels = daily.map((data) => {
    return data.event_date;
});
```

```
const dailyData = daily.map((data) => {
    return data.listener
});
```

Now I have 2 new arrays that I can use, but it doesn't seem like the best approach. Am I right or am I wrong?

Comment: Efficient in which regard ? Original array has large objects ? Original array has a lots of elements ? How do "large" and "lot" are defined ? What is your objective ? Do you have a basic benchmark / example to work on ?

Comment: This being said, your method seem fine to me, and more importantly it seems very readable. You should worry about micro-optimize this code only if you can actually see a problem here with the data you are planning to use)

Comment: For efficiency not creating another 2 array's might be an idea.  A nice way of doing that with modern JS would be with a generator..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) therefore you only iterate over the length of the array once.

```js
const daily = [
    { event_date: "2019-10-18", listener: 3 },
    { event_date: "2019-10-19", listener: 3 },
    { event_date: "2019-10-20", listener: 1 }
];

const { dailyLabels, dailyData } = daily.reduce(
    (result, { event_date, listener }) => {
        result.dailyLabels.push(event_date);
        result.dailyData.push(listener);

        return result;
    },
    { dailyLabels: [], dailyData: [] }
);

console.log(dailyLabels);
console.log(dailyData);
```

Comment: pst, @Taki answer was before mine. We pressed post at the same time.

Comment: Do you have any information about the "efficient" part, which was the original question ?

Comment: @Pac0 yes I do "you only iterate over the length of the array once"

Comment: indeed, I was about to say "apart from that, do you have actual performance data to prove your point" ? Because, if you iterate once with 1 second per element, or iterating twice with 0.1 sec per element, the "two iterations" part is still faster.

Comment: @Pac0, "you only iterate over the length of the array once" justifies and clearly explains the efficiency of using reduce over 2 maps. You are welcome to record the function times at scale, but its a hardcoded fact that doing the same thing 2 times is going to take longer than doing it once.

Comment: @DanStarns, not really, I guess the complexity will be O(nk) either ways (`n` being the number of object in the array, and `k` being the number of keys per object)

Comment: You either loop through the array once, but you have to loop through each key (your approach) O(nk), or the opposite: loop through the array as many times as keys (O(kn)) (OP's approach)

Comment: Anyway, complexity != speed. complexity gives a clue about the asymptotic behaviour of "performance" only. A low complexity algorithm can perform much worse than a high complexity one for some data. Also, it was not precised by OP if time was the target, or the memory, or the power usage, etc...

Comment: @Taki That's data ! Thanks. Interestingly, the test shows that chromes take indeed twice as long for the 2 maps instead of one reduce (as DanStarns predicted), however Firefox was onl 18% slower ffor the 2 maps. In any case, reduce proved to be faster in this situation (with a ~ million elements)

Comment: @Taki, good point, it's definitely worth a mention that the efficiency is dependant on each implementation.

Comment: Ah, I'm wrong, in Firefox 69, the multiple maps perform better with this data! for Firefox 70 though, multiple maps is 20% slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` to do that

```js
daily.reduce((rs, el) => {rs.listeners.push(el.listener); rs.event_dates.push(el.event_date); return rs;}, {event_dates: [], listeners: []})
```